# Returning Permissions From Web Api to AngularJs client

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I am building an application with a set of user types. I have a .Net MVC 5 Web Api web service and an angularjs SPA. I would like to have my SPA display pages relative to the user type logged in. I am authenticating with bearer tokens which I then store in localStorage.

I have thought of making web api, return the token with the user's claims and roles, I can then use this information to decide what pages to display to the user, however, I worry that the user can easily alter this information.

Could you please advise how I can achieve this without introducing a security exploit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is constant battle between the ease of a single-download and personal protection.  You could ship additional pages along with the ACL payload, or allow the users to get crafty and validate actions performed on the server side, preventing inappropriate viewings or updates.

Answer (score 0):

In the server side which is your controller, you should add some authorization filter. Resolve the token to the requesting user and verify authorization. Implement some caching so you are not querying the database (or some user store) each time. You don't have control on the client-side. They can alter however they want in the display and compose their request. So that is why it is important to put these authentication/authorization in each request.